# How do I update a column's value based on the current time?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs

In PostgreSQL, I want the ability to update a column, 'closed', based on another column (close_time) compared to the current time. How do I check if the time now is greater than the close_time and update the column 'closed' to true if it now is greater than the closing time?

Comment: Is the word “closed” a typo? Or are you saying you want to mark a row as “closed” by updating a certain field when it’s stored moment value is past the current moment? Edit your Question to clarify.

Comment: Also, if you are using Postgres with a certain programming framework, e.g. PHP, then please tell us what that framework is.

Comment: Yea, sorry I meant closed as a column. I'm v new to stack overflow and still getting a hang of how to properly write questions. @TimBiegeleisen, I don't think so. So I have a database postgresql, and I am using loopback ( a node.js framwork) that interacts with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using loopback 4, you can do this using update method of repository.

```
await this.userRepository.updateById(id, user);
```

If you want this to happen automatically at DB level, then you can use DB triggers in postgres. See a tutorial here - http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

You don't even necessarily use a bona fide column for this, you could instead just do the comparison when you select.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME > close_time AS cmp
FROM yourTable;
```

You could also put the above logic into a view.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I'm using loopback which builds the API for me so I'm not sure how to directly query the database. I guess I could do that on the front end?